# Inspect with Chrome Developer Tools | Reattach to target

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a quick way to re-attach the target without closing the window and press inspect?

Maybe some kind of deeplink which i can open after compiling?

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

Comment: This is also really annoying me. I end up with loads of debug windows open each time I recompile my Cordova apps.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of when the connection to the target gets lost?

Comment: For me there are mainly 2 cases: 1. I start compiling and my VM/Device is not started or connected and the code gets deployed on the device. Here it would be nice to have a way of automatically open the Debugging Tools via  script/link/exe or whatever. 2. The VM/Device is running the actual code, the code gets recompiled and redeployed which terminates the running app together with the running debug Session.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean... And it's still an issue, in 2022! Why isn't there an easy way to tell Chrome to re-attach to a certain canvas when connection is lost (due to the WebView restarting...)